# Does Android support German language using phonegap (does not show German umlaut Ü)

Tags: android, cordova

`Übersicht` - `ÄÖÜ`
These type of characters are not supported in android using phonegap.
Can any one help?

Comment: Even if it isnt the solution I will write it as a condensed answer below and delete my comments here, so other may profit from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Please check at first, if your document is saved with the right encoding.
  Here: UTF-8

  You can usually change via the file properties of your editor
  *Programmers Notepad:*   File - Properties - Encoding - UTF-8
  *Eclipse:*    Project - Properties - Resource: Text File Encoding - Other [UTF-8]
- Make sure you have the correct meta tag in your document.

  Html: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8;" lang="de" />`
- Use the HTML notation of special characters.

  `&Uuml;` instead of `Ü`

  Check out [THIS](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php) reference.

Comment: I got a solution,Just copy the character into notepad and then transfer the Character from notepad to your code.